# Flutter Backend Application

Tags: flutter, backend

My goal is to create an application on Flutter. My application will integrate a map where users will be visible live on the map (even when they move). I would like to know which database to use?
I am comfortable with SQL but is it possible to integrate in a table the live position of the users?
Should I use a cloud database like FireBase?
And finally, which database will be the cheapest for an application like mine?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is fast prototyping I would look into "Firebase Realtime Database". It can do what you want. Pricing is a quite subjective matter.

Comment: Concerning the price, I wonder if it's more expensive to use Firebase or to use OVH or One and one servers?

Comment: There is no general answer. It really depends on the use-case and your personal development costs. As long as your application does not have a big target size, firebase is not that bad. Just remember that is a big dependency to build upon. Switching away can be quite costly.